# Automatically update an Outlook Meeting's Reminder when rescheduled

Tags: vba, outlook, triggers

I'm trying to find a way (rule or VBA I'm agnostic) to automatically change the Reminder value when a meeting is rescheduled.

I've poked around but been unable to find a way to trigger on a change to the meeting's date-time, which seems like the first step to getting to what I want, so guidance on what the right/closest trigger might be would be enough for me to get started (I should be able to muddle through actually checking and reseting the Reminder once I have the trigger).

Background: The ultimate goal is to have the script/rule make sure that when a meeting is rescheduled, its Reminder is not "None" (in the case that a meeting is rescheduled after the reminder has been dismissed being the prime example). In the happiest of worlds, the script would be agnostic to who owns the meeting (which is why it seemed best to key off the meeting time changing).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a very old known problem. `+1` for visibility, good luck! (I don't think it can be done with a rule, but I'm sure this can be done with VBA) Though, one way to do that would be to make a **new** meeting which would create a proper reminder.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I've found similar threads other places, but never with an answer so I figured I'd try here.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I stumbled upon it from Google while searching for an answer. Ended up creating some VBA to notify myself if the meeting reminder is set to less than 10 minutes (Outlook 2013):

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
'Application_ItemSend fires everytime you hit send on any mail, meeting, etc.
Dim m As Variant
'check to see if the item you're about to send is a meeting invite:
If TypeName(Item) = "MeetingItem" Then
    'if the reminder is not set at all, or set to less than 10 minutes, give the user the option to cancel sending
    If (Not Item.GetAssociatedAppointment(False).ReminderSet) Or (Item.GetAssociatedAppointment(False).ReminderMinutesBeforeStart < 10) Then
        m = MsgBox("Your meeting reminder is set to 10 minutes or less. Do you still want to send?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo + vbMsgBoxSetForeground)
            If m = vbNo Then Cancel = True
            End If
    End If
handleError:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox "Outlook Error: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

See the ItemChange event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865866%28v=office.14%29.aspx

```
Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items 

Public Sub Application_Startup() 
  Set myOlItems = _
    Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items 
End Sub 

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object) 
    debug.print item.subject
End Sub
```